# Tying an HTML slider 'max' range to an input field's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uislider

How does one set the 'max' range value of a jQuery uiSlider to the value of a user editable input field?

Here is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/djallen2882/qLcpdoc4/5/)

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
   </div>
    <div>
<input name="Profit" id="Profit" value="How do I tie the 'max' range to this input field?" style="font-weight: bold;" />
<input name="label" id="label" value="deal" style="font-weight: bold;" />

</div>

<div role="main" class="ui-content">

  <ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
      <div id="SlideDesign">

      <input type="range" name="pSlider" id="pSlider" min="-1000" max="600" value="300" data-highlight="true" />
       </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following JavaScript is working

```
document.getElementById("Profit").onchange = function() {MaxPCalculate()};   function MaxPCalculate() { var MaxProfit = document.getElementById("pSlider"); MaxProfit.max = document.getElementById("Profit").value; }
```

~[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djallen2882/09z9nLmf/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: sorry I misunderstood the question.

Use the following JQuery

```
var value = $('#Profit').val (); //Get the profit input
$('#pSlider').attr('max',value); //Set the value of the max attribute
```

Comment: Thanks CVarg - This sets the value of the profit input to the value of the 'max' attribute that has been defined in the HTML tag. I need the max attribute to be adjusted to match the USER input of the profit field.

Comment: I updated the code to get the result I was looking for. Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djallen2882/qLcpdoc4/)

Answer (score 0):

This change in script changes the value and colors on slider but actually does not slide the bar.

```
        $(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function() {



      HighlightColor($("#pSlider"));
      $("#pSlider").on("change", function() {
        HighlightColor($(this));
      });

      function HighlightColor(slider) {
        var theVal = slider.val();
        var color = "#0DB8B5";
        if (theVal < -750) {
          color = "#D92727";
          document.getElementById("label").value = "Red Deal :(";
          document.getElementById("label").style.color = "red";
        } else if (theVal < -425) {
          color = "#FFAF33";
          document.getElementById("label").value = "Orange Deal :/";
          document.getElementById("label").style.color = "orange";
        } else if (theVal < 0) {
          color = "#E5E819";
          document.getElementById("label").value = "Yellow Deal :|";
          document.getElementById("label").style.color = "#E5E819";
        } else if (theVal < 400) {
          color = "#0FB10A";
          document.getElementById("label").value = "Green Deal :)";
          document.getElementById("label").style.color = "#0FB10A";
        } else {
          color = "#10F909";
          document.getElementById("label").value = "Bright Green Deal :D";
          document.getElementById("label").style.color = "#10F909";
        }
        slider.closest(".ui-slider").find(".ui-slider-bg").css("background-color", color);
      }

      $('#Profit').on("change", function () {
            //alert($(this).val());
        $("#pSlider").val($(this).val());
        //$("#pSlider").slider( "instance" );
        HighlightColor($("#pSlider"));
            });


    });
```

Comment: Thank you T Shah. This is helpful, even if its not answering my original question. I will add this scripting into the my final version.

Comment: T Shah - do you by chance know how I can get the slider to 'slide' as well as adjusting the Highlight color? - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djallen2882/qLcpdoc4/)